# MYSQL BIT column return unexpected result ( ┌ )

Tags: php, mysql, database, types

Querying the database to my server returns an unexpected result.

My Column is simple type BIT for compare in 0 or 1

I have also tried true or false, but it is the same problem.

Localhost its works but NameCheapServer return ( ┌ ) **is alt+218 if not view** <- symbol unexpected

**Note:** In Localhost with WAMP Works but in mi server in NameCheap NO

```
require ('CONF_con.php');

$RE = $db->query("SELECT state FROM users WHERE ID = 2 " )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Query simple in column user

$n = 3;
echo "Numeral is> ".$n;
echo "<br />Mysql Column Type Numeric BIT return> ".$RE[0]['state'];


if ($RE[0]['state'] == 1){ // Here problem => Locahost MySqL return 1, but namecheap server unexpected return-> ( «┌» ) <- Not is R in lowercase Why?
   echo "<br /><br />normal 1 + 3"; // expect 4
}

if ($RE[0]['state'] == true){ // Validate but column no is 1
   echo "<br /><br />normal 1 + 3 with TRUE"; // expect 4 => with TRUE
}

$suma = $RE[0]['state']+$n;
echo "<br /><br /><b>TOTAL> ".$suma."</b>______________//expect 4 four";
```

My configuration in localhost y NameCheapServer:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ZQm18pI.png]

[image]

Whats is the problem?

Comment: Are other queries working in NameCheap?

Comment: Please show the exact error message, it's hard to understand the way you posted it.

Comment: @Barmar Mysql Return «┌» Symbol wirte with alt+218 ┌

Comment: That's not an error message. It sounds like a character encoding problem. Make sure you have the same `CHARSET` setting.

Comment: Charset looks fine, I would check the configured collation (of the involved tables/columns). Also note the server is using MariaDB 10+ while you're using MySQL 5.7, where if I remember correctly `BIT` didn't quite behave properly then

Comment: The BIT type is not a literal _bit_, it's a _bitfield_. The mysql driver is likely returning it as a binary string that displays oddly according to whatever encoding you're using. If you just want to store a `0` or `1` value just use a TINYINT instead. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html

Comment: @Sammitch Change the charset and collation of the server, database and table but it doesn't work. I am tired, I will use TINYINT that does not fail. Thanks for all the help.